# Как максимально быстро вывести на экран картинку в Windows 7 через winapi на Си?

Tags: c, winapi, изображения

Крайне важна высокая скорость вывода на экран, т. к. картинками буду рисовать элементы интерфейса моей программы.

Я пока нашёл один подходящий способ: картинка в .bmp файле, в начале работы программы она будет загружена в память через LoadImage(), хранится там всё время, пока работает программа и выводится на экран при необходимости с помощью BitBlt().

Вот кусок кода из инета, который у меня работает:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;
static HDC memBit;
static HBITMAP hBitmap;
static BITMAP bm;

switch (message) {
case WM_CREATE:
    hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, TEXT("1.bmp"), IMAGE_BITMAP,
        0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
    GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);
    hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    memBit = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    SelectObject(memBit, hBitmap);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
    break;

case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 265, 175, memBit, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);//вывлд изображения
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
...
```

Вопрос: можно ли выводить картинку на экран быстрее, или использовать этот код?

Comment: Не верю, что вы реально упираетесь в производительность скорости вывода картинки. Если, конечно, вы пишете не под Пентиум-2.

Answer (score 3):

Строго говоря под WinApi другого способа и не предусмотрено, ну да ладно.

По идее ваш метод будет работать очень быстро. Камушком может стать то, что система выгрузит растр из видео в системную память. В этом, случае можно сильно потерять на трансфере. В DirectX есть возможность явно указать где хранить картинку в видео или системной памяти и гарантированно избежать такого развития. Хотя с другой стороны, при сегодняшних объемах памяти очень маловероятно что растр погрузится в системную память.

Рекомендую вам оставить как есть, если станет лагать тогда и думать про директиксы и опенджиэли.

Если проект строго под винду, то OpenGL использовать не стоит, поумолчанию он будет медленее DirectX.

Answer (score 2):

Быстрее, чем BitBlt или [SetDIBitsToDevice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd162974(v=vs.85).aspx) в GDI не бывает.

Если же вам нужно еще быстрее, то смотрите в сторону Direct2D или OpenGL.

Answer (score 2):

Что значит "быстрее"? Сейчас при каждой перерисовке окна у вас выводится изображение. Выводится с обычной скоростью, незаметной глазу, практически весь интерфейс всех окон так и работает. Оставляйте этот код, он для этого и предназначен. Тока memBit логически не вяжется, переименуйте в dcBitmap.

Answer (score 2):

Используй GDI+

```
Graphics g(hdc);
Image im(L"Имя.png");
g.DrawImage( &im, x, y, width, height);
```

**Обновление**

Я, конечно не гуру в WinApi, но очевидно, что код выше, как минимум короче, следовательно ресурсов на его использование уйдёт меньше. Плюс есть выбор: формат файла(В GDI использовать не Bitmap, опять же дольше...), плюс alpha-канал

```
#include<gdiplus.h>
#pragma comment (lib,"gdiplus.lib")
using namespace Gdiplus;
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hi,HINSTANCE,LPSTR,int csh)
{
    GdiplusStartupInput in;
    ULONG_PTR token;
    GdiplusStartup(&token,&in,NULL);
    ...
    GdiplusShutdown(&token);
    return msg.Wparam;
}
void DrawPic(HDC hdc)
{
    Graphics g(hdc);
    Image im(L"blabla.png");
    g.drawImage(&im,x,y,width,height);
}

LONG WINAPI wndPrc(HWND hwnd,UINT message,WPARAM wp,LPARAM lp)
{
    HDC hdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    ...
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc=BeginPaint(hwnd,&ps);
        DrawPic(hdc);
        EndPaint(hwnd,&ps);
    break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: "очевидно, что код выше, как минимум короче, следовательно ресурсов на его использование уйдёт меньше" - Одно из другого не следует. Смотря насколько "прожорливы" используемые функции. В данном случае нужны бенчмарки.